# @AuraEnabled method - when I call this from client I get an error

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura

Apex methods that are to be cached must be marked as @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
client side

```
  @wire(updateLots,{victim : '$payedLots'})
updateLots(data, error) {
    console.log('inside payed');
    if(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    if(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

and server side

```
  @AuraEnabled
public static string updateLots(List<String> victim) {
    try {
        List<Lot__c> lotList = [select id from Lot__c where id in :victim];
        for(Lot__c  lot : lotList) {
            lot.payed__c = true;
        }
        update lotList;
    }
    catch(DmlException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    return 'Success';
}
```

Can anyone tells me what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use a wire to invoke a non-cacheable aura enabled function. In addition, a cacheable one cannot perform DML operations.

You need to convert the client to use imperative invocation of this DML-based aura enabled function.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex) for details.

Comment: By what way can pass parameters?

Comment: Visit the documentation page I linked to and search for "apexImperativeMethodWithParams". This will lead you to [where you can find the details](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithParams/apexImperativeMethodWithParams.js).